# How can a query expanding a delimited list be optimized?

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle and recently ran into the following query. I'm trying to understand what it's doing and hopefully rewrite it to optimize it. In this example, :NameList would be a comma separated list (like: "Bob,Bill,Fred") and then :N_NameList would be the number of tokens (in above example, 3)

```
SELECT ... FROM
(
  SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(:NameList,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL, 'i') Name
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= :N_NameList
) x
INNER JOIN PEOPLE ppl
  ON ppl.Name LIKE x.Name
 ...
```

From what I can tell, it expands out the delimited list into unique rows and then joins it with the following tables for each name, but I'm not sure if that's all it's doing. If that is the case, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this instead:

```
select ...
  from people ppl
 where instr (','||:NameList||',',
              ','||ppl.name||',') > 0;
```

Comment: This is great! After playing around with it a bit, I realized it'll also have to support basic matching (eg, input like "Bob%,Bill%"), but looks like there's a regex_instr I can use for that case, can probably just replace to swap out the % for a regex equivalent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> is there a better way to accomplish this?

Well, you could get rid of N_NameList because you can easily count number of tokens. This doesn't mean that it is a *better* way, it's just a *different* option. To be honest, it is probably *slower* option than yours as I have to *calculate* something that you entered as a parameter.

As this example is based on SQLPlus, I've used `&` instead of `:` for substitution variables. `&&` means that it'll "remember" previously entered value (otherwise, I should type NameList twice.

Your current query:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('&namelist', '[^,]+', 1, level, 'i') name
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= &n_namelist;
Enter value for namelist: Bob,Bill,Fred
Enter value for n_namelist: 3
Bob
Bill
Fred
```

Calculated *N_NameList* (using `REGEXP_COUNT`):

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('&&namelist', '[^,]+', 1, level, 'i') name
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= regexp_count('&&namelist', ',') + 1;
Enter value for namelist: Bob,Bill,Fred
Bob
Bill
Fred
```